# Separate Iterations of arrayed _POST variables

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach

I'm having some trouble with a form designed to insert fixtures into a database for a sports league.

The previous page contains a form which defines through _POST "area"/"division"/"season" and contains an iterated (to ten) loop of a group of fixture fields, which are defined as having arrayed names like "hometeam[$i]", "awayteam[$i]" and so forth.

On the page which processes the input of the fixtures, I need to pull each individual iteration of the form - i.e. "hometeam[1]" "awayteam[1]" and so on - from within the $_POST array and insert that into the MYSQL database before moving onto the next one. I'm totally in over my head with foreach and if clauses so I thought it best to ask here.

```
<?php
$a=1;
while($a<11){
foreach($_POST as $key){
if(is_array($key))
{foreach($key as $value1=>$value2){
    if($value1=$a){
    if($_POST='hometeam')$home_id=$value2;
    else if($_POST='awayteam')$away_id=$value2;
    else if($_POST='day')$day=$value2;
    else if($_POST='month')$month=$value2;
    else if($_POST='year')$year=$value2;
    else if($_POST='hour')$hour=$value2;
    else if($_POST='mins')$mins=$value2;}
    $date = ($year . "-" . $month . "-" . $day);
    $time = (($hour) . ":" . ($mins) . ":00");
    $enter_query = "INSERT INTO matches (home_id, away_id, date, time, league_id) VALUES ('$home_id', '$away_id', '$date', '$time', '$league_id'";
    if($hour != "00"){
$enter_result = mysql_query($enter_query);
}}}

}
$a++;
}
?>
```

If anyone can point at where I'm blatantly going wrong here, I'd be immensely grateful. I'm sure it's not meant to be this hard but I'm flustered and can't see past what I've typed, and I'm not sure my knowledge is accurate as-is.

Running a print_r on the array gives out the following structure:

```
Array ( [area] => 1 [season] => 2 [division] => 1 [hometeam]
=> Array ( [1] => 17 [2] => 2 [3] => 12 [4] => 17 [5] => 17
[6] => 17 [7] => 17 [8] => 17 [9] => 17 [10] => 17 ) [awayteam]
=> Array ( [1] => 6 [2] => 4 [3] => 10 [4] => 17 [5]
```

where the same 10fold structure continues with arrays indexed as hometeam, awayteam, day, month, year, hour, mins.

Comment: Is each $_POST variable an array with the team id as the index?

Comment: No. The first few $_POST variables aren't arrays at all. I've updated the question to include the result of running print_r on the $_POST array.

Comment: You have forgotten a `)` after your query. Also, you are using `mysql`, **and** not sanitizing your inputs. See [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on sanitizing things. The security side is not something I've been occupied with but I'm gonna change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_POST` is an associative array so its values are accessed through key names, for example `$_POST['hometeam']`. This would contain an array of each of the `hometeam[]` values.

The second thing I see is that you need to remember that the = operator is for assigning a value, and == is for comparison. So if ($value = $a) would assign $a to $value and return the result of that, not a logical test.

You should considered replacing the big chain of if/else with a select block. But that's optional and I've left that as is from your example.

My final suggestion is that whist you don't have to have whitespace, it does make it a lot easier to review code when it's not working properly.

I haven't tested this code but this is how I would rework what you have.

```
<?php
    $a=1;
    while ($a<11) {
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            if (isarray($value)) {
                foreach ($value as $value1 => $value2) {
                    if ($value1 == $a){
                        if ($key == 'hometeam') { $home_id = $value2; }
                        else if($key == 'awayteam') { $away_id = $value2; }
                        else if($key == 'day') { $day = $value2; }
                        else if($key == 'month') { $month = $value2; }
                        else if($key == 'year') { $year = $value2; }
                        else if($key == 'hour') { $hour = $value2; }
                        else if($key == 'mins'){ $mins = $value2;}
                        $date = ($year . "-" . $month . "-" . $day);
                        $time = (($hour) . ":" . ($mins) . ":00");
                        $enter_query = "INSERT INTO matches (home_id, away_id, date, time, league_id) VALUES ('$home_id', '$away_id', '$date', '$time', '$league_id')";
                        if ($hour != "00"){
                            $enter_result = mysql_query($enter_query);
                        }
                }
            }

        }
        $a++;
    }
?>
```

I hope this gets you on the right track at least.

EDIT: I've refactored this down a bit. It doesn't do any checking of what is returned on the form (which is a security issue) but that's outside the scope of this question..

```
<?php
    $a=1;
    while ($a<11) {

        $date = ($_POST['day'][$a] "-" . $_POST['month'][$a] . "-" . $_POST['day'][$a]);
        $time = ($_POST['hour'][$a] . ":" . $_POST['mins'][$a] . ":00");
        $hometeam = $_POST['hometeam'][$a];
        $awayteam = $_POST['awayteam'][$a];
        $enter_query = "INSERT INTO matches (home_id, away_id, date, time, league_id) VALUES ('$hometeam', '$awayteam', '$date', '$time', '$league_id')";
        if ($_POST['hour'][$a] != "00"){
            $enter_result = mysql_query($enter_query);
        }
        $a++;
    }
?>
```

I can't see where league_id comes from. If it is a part of $_POST you can reference it in the same way (if it is not an array then don't use the [$a]).

Comment: I appreciate those pointers, particularly the equivalence correction! Having made those updates to the code, it's no longer returning ten warnings, but the insertion still isn't working. I suppose I could bring the iteration up a level by saying: foreach($_POST['hometeam'] as $value1 => $value2, and repeating for each arrayed $_POST variable.

Comment: @AdamKnott I just added some refactored code which is a lot simpler and should work. I would be interested to know what error you are getting when trying to insert the item into the table.

Comment: @Nicholsophy thanks for the refactored code, I see what you're trying to do, but I'm not sure what happened. It inserts the value "Array[1,2,3] into the three records under home_id and away_id and the correct data into the date and time fields. Any thoughts?

Comment: The $league_id element comes from a definition further up the page which SELECTS * FROM leagues WHERE division=$_POST['division'] and so on (it does now, anyway!)

Comment: Ignore my comment re: date and time not working, they work perfectly.

Comment: @AdamKnott I'm confused. You never said date or time weren't working.

Comment: What you posted works perfectly (given a concatenate in the $date definition) except I removed the quotation marks around hometeam and awayteam which I think might well be what caused the odd Array[1] etc. to show up in the database. How do I get around this given that there are too many quote marks within each other?

Comment: @AdamKnott You could create two new variables above the insert `$hometeam = $_POST['hometeam'][$a];` and same for awayteam. Then use that variable in the mysql insert. Sorry it's been ages since I've done this in the real world :) Let me know if that sorts it for you and I'll update the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Haha, I really should've thought of that! Absolutely perfect. I am forever in your gratitude. Now to go about sanitizing this input!

Comment: No problem at all. Don't forget to mark the answer so that this will be closed off. Good luck with the sanitizing @AdamKnott

Answer (score 0):

You can use php variables to create other php variables as well.

So, to convert the post variables into your corresponding variables, place the variable inside a "${$variable}"


I would also recommend if you can, to pass in your year, month, day as any date **string** and

 use **date("Y-m-d",strtotime($dateStr))** to format it.


You can also use php date and mktime to format your time instead of concatinating
**date("H:i:00",mktime($hour,$mins))**;


Also, make sure you sanitize your output 
http://www.php-developer.org/best-practices-when-sanitizing-post-to-prevent-mysql-and-xss-attacks/

```
for ($ix=0; $ix<11; $ix++) {
    foreach ($_POST as $key=>$stat) {
        // If it is an array, extract value according to index ($ix)
        /* Update
        if(is_array($stat))
            ${$key}=sanitize_str($key[$stat][$ix]);
        else
            ${$key}=sanitize_str($key[$stat]);
        */
        //UPDATE!
        if(is_array($stat))
            ${$key}=sanitize_str($stat[$ix]);
        else
            ${$key}=sanitize_str($stat);
    }
    // If you pass date as separate values
    $date = $year."-".$month."-".$day;
    // If you pass date as a sting, use
    // $date=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($date));
    $time = $hour.":".$mins.":00");

    $enter_query = "INSERT INTO matches (home_id, away_id, date, time, league_id) 
                VALUES ('$home_id', '$away_id', '$date', '$time', '$league_id')";
    if($hour != "00"){
        $enter_result = mysql_query($enter_query);
    }
}

function sanitize_str($data){
    $data=trim($data);
    $data=htmlspecialchars($data);

    $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
    return $data;
}
```

I haven't fully tested this yet, but it should work.

In the ${$key} lines, if $key is the value "hometeam", ${$key} becomes ${hometeam}, which is the same thing as saying $hometeam

Comment: This is returning "Warning: Illegal offset type in" around " ${$key}=sanitize_str($key[$stat]);"

Comment: updated. change "if(is_array(${$key}))" to if(is_array($stat))

Comment: Is still warning the same thing, but just once instead of 10 times, and fatal error-ing with the explanation: Cannot use string offset as an array (same line)